# How do you specify the channel .NET remoting will use to perform a callback

Tags: .net, callback, remoting, channel

I have a client (and server) with 2 channels set up on different protocols, lets say X:// and Y://.

If I call a service (over remoting) from client (C) on a server (S) that needs to perform a callback to the client (so S->C) is there a way to specify which channel to use?  In my use case I want any calls from X:// to callback over X:// and any calls over Y:// to callback over Y://.

My current solution is to implement a custom serialization surrogate (and selector) for each channel for MarshalByRefObjects that removes the URI of the other channel from the SerializationInfo when serializing them.  Similar to:

```
            RemotingServices.GetObjectData(obj, info, context);
            IChannelInfo channelInfo = (IChannelInfo)info.GetValue("channelInfo", typeof(IChannelInfo));
            channelInfo.ChannelData = channelInfo.ChannelData.Where(x =>
            {
                ChannelDataStore ds = x as ChannelDataStore;
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    if (!(ds.ChannelUris.Length > 0 && ds.ChannelUris[0].StartsWith("Y://")))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }).ToArray();
```

This actually works but just feels wrong (ex: relying on "channelInfo" string in the populated SerializationInfo).  Does anyone know of a better solution?  I've looked pretty throughly through RemotingServices.GetObjectData but still couldn't figure out where it gets the URI list from.